# ffmpeg: Second lower third does not appear

Tags: ffmpeg

On a video I am producing, I am overlaying a digital on screen graphic on the lower right corner (branding logo).  I am overlaying an 11 second two-tiered lower third at the beginning of the video (Speaker's Name with their title below their name).  Later in the video a second speaker is introduced and I am trying to add a second two-tiered lower third for the second speaker.  I do this on a weekly basis and everything before the second lower third works like magic.  However, the second lower third never appears.  Here is the code I am using:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel 56 -report \
    -ss 00:25:00 \
    -i 00005.MTS \
    -i ./constants/edu_logo.svg \
    -i ./constants/name_animation_dr_johnson.mp4 \
    -i ./constants/name_animation_dr_halmilton.mp4 \
    -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=400:122[logo]; \
    [0:v][logo]overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w-80:y=main_h-overlay_h-80[v-l]; \
    [v-l][2:v]overlay=x=0:y=0:enable='between(t,0,10.5)'[v-l-a]; \
    [v-l-a][3:v]overlay=x=0:y=0:enable='between(t,15,25.5)'[v-l-a-a]" \
    -vcodec libx264 -preset fast \
            -flags +cgop -pix_fmt yuv420p \
            -b:v 2M -movflags +faststart \
    -map "[v-l-a-a]" -map 0:a -t 30 my_test.mp4
```

What do I need to modify to get the second lower third to appear?

Ubuntu Studio 18.04.2 LTS
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
i7-2600k @ 3.4GHz
8 Gigs of RAM
GeForce GTX 970

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overlay filter syncs by timestamps i.e. it overlays 2nd input's frame with timestamp X on main input's frame with timestamp X.  Barring certain circumstances like the use of `-copyts`, timestamps start from zero. So, when your 2nd lower-third overlay enters its active timeline, there are no corresponding frames from the secondary input.

Solution: offset the input's timestamps to start from overlay start time.

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel 56 -report \
    -ss 00:25:00 \
    -i 00005.MTS \
    -i ./constants/edu_logo.svg \
    -i ./constants/name_animation_dr_johnson.mp4 \
    -itsoffset 15 -i ./constants/name_animation_dr_halmilton.mp4 \
    -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=400:122[logo]; \
    [0:v][logo]overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w-80:y=main_h-overlay_h-80[v-l]; \
    [v-l][2:v]overlay=x=0:y=0:enable='between(t,0,10.5)'[v-l-a]; \
    [v-l-a][3:v]overlay=x=0:y=0:enable='between(t,15,25.5)'[v-l-a-a]" \
    -vcodec libx264 -preset fast \
            -flags +cgop -pix_fmt yuv420p \
            -b:v 2M -movflags +faststart \
    -map "[v-l-a-a]" -map 0:a -t 30 my_test.mp4
```

Comment: the magic has returned.  Your answer is perfect.  I truly appreciate your help and expertise.  Thank you!